# Return median value array in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to match the value in an array and return the median value found in the fourth column of an array in another sheet B_Sheet!B1:B65404

Since Vlookup only returns the first value I tried using Index and Match but not sure why it failed.

Tried this but **didnt** work `ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(MEDIAN(FILTER(INDEX(B_Sheet!D1:D65404,MATCH(B5:B36518,B_Sheet!B1:B65404,0)),LEN(INDEX(B_Sheet!D1:D65404,MATCH(B5:B36518,B_Sheet!B1:B65404,0)))>0)),""))`

For reference, this Vlookup **did** work:

```
ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B5:B36518,B_Sheet!B1:E65404, 4, FALSE),""))
```

Example1:
With formula in top of second column of **Sheet1**

| Name | Array Return Median value |
| --- | --- |
| James | 5 (formula is here) |
| Robert | 6 |

And looking up in the next sheet....
:

**B_Sheet!**

| Name | Test Scores |
| --- | --- |
| James | 3 |
| Robert | 4 |
| James | 5 |
| Robert | 6 |
| James | 7 |
| Robert | 8 |

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show us a sample of the data you have and desired results. Especially a link to a sample sheet tends to go a long way.

Comment: ok I added tables

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could do this. To answer your question using a formula that calculates the median based on the adjacent cells names you could use:

```
=IFERROR(BYROW(A2:A, LAMBDA(xx,MEDIAN(FILTER(B_Sheet!B:B, B_Sheet!A:A=xx)))),"")
```

However I would suggest the following formula which just groups and averages all names in `B_Sheet`.

```
=QUERY(B_Sheet!A:B,"SELECT A,AVG(B) WHERE A IS NOT NULL GROUP BY A LABEL AVG(B) ''")
```

The second formula can be pasted in cell `A1` and it will populate Column A with a name and Column B with the average for that name. You can further sort this and filter it down as desired if you do not want every single name. Of course this calculates `AVERAGE` and not `MEDIAN`.